# Error inserting data to SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, syntax, insert, android-sqlite

I have a problem inserting data while inserting the data with @hotmail

this is the error

```
11-28 08:07:19.684: E/CREATE TABLE ERROR(21840): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "@hotmail": syntax error: , while compiling: INSERT INTO user_table SELECT han AS userName,  123 AS password,  han@hotmail.com AS emailAddress,  0123456678 AS phoneNuber,  50.00 AS balance  UNION SELECT felicia, 123, felicia@hotmail.com, 0123456678, 100.00
```

but when I removed @hotmail, I get another problem with no such column

```
11-28 08:16:06.704: E/CREATE TABLE ERROR(24403): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: felicia: , while compiling: INSERT INTO user_table SELECT han AS userName,  123 AS password,  han AS emailAddress,  0123456678 AS phoneNuber,  50.00 AS balance  UNION SELECT felicia, 123, felicia, 0123456678, 100.00
```

this is my table

```
String createuser = "CREATE TABLE user_table (_id integer primary key autoincrement not null, "
                + "userName text,"
                + "password text,"
                + "emailAddress text,"
                + "phoneNumber text,"
                + "balance text);";
```

this is my data insert

```
String data = " INSERT INTO user_table SELECT han AS userName, "
                + " 123 AS password, "
                + " han@hotmail.com AS emailAddress, "
                + " 0123456678 AS phoneNuber, "
                + " 50.00 AS balance "
                + " UNION SELECT felicia, 123, felicia@hotmail.com, 0123456678, 100.00 ";

        try
        {
            db.execSQL(createuser);
            db.execSQL(data);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("CREATE TABLE ERROR", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: -1 *again.* See the comments in your previous question for my recommendation of how to craft and test queries. Blindly guessing as to what the errors are without immediate feedback (as *you would get from a CLI*) are not keys to success. Also, when you write the query "for real" in Android, use placeholders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bah. As a [potential] developer, you are *expected* to work out syntax issues on your own.

There are two important steps here

1. establishing an environment in which syntax/behavior can be easily tested and
2. understanding (and actively learning about) the syntax.

For starters, let's use a *database command-line interface*. Either use `sqlite3.exe` on a PC, whatever is available on Android (and there are several!) or something like [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com). I'll use SQLFiddle so that we can all participate, whoohoo!

The next bit is to understand the syntax. The syntax for [SQLite INSERT](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) is well-documneted with graphical train tracks. (A freebie: text literals in ANSI SQL syntax are written like 'a string'.)

That being said, see [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/b644b/1). Feel free to play with it.

```
CREATE TABLE user_table (
  _id integer primary key autoincrement not null, 
  userName text,
  password text,
  emailAddress text,
  phoneNumber text,
  balance text);

-- INSERT from a select
-- This REQUIRES that the column as specified after the table name
insert into user_table (userName, password, emailAddress, phoneNumber, balance)
select
  'han' as userName,
   123 AS password,
  'han@hotmail.com' AS emailAddress,
  '0123456678' AS phoneNuber,
  50.00 AS balance;

-- Insert from VALUES, if they match and are in-order, do not
-- need the column names.
-- Insert NULL into _id to get the auto-increment behavior.
insert into user_table
values (NULL, 'han2', 123, 'han@hotmail.com', '0123456678', 50.00);

-- Multi-insert from SELECT (could also be done with VALUES)
insert into user_table (userName, password, emailAddress, phoneNumber, balance)
select
  'han3' as userName,
   123 AS password,
  'han@hotmail.com' AS emailAddress,
  '0123456678' AS phoneNuber,
  50.00 AS balance
union select
  'han4' as userName,
   123 AS password,
  'han@hotmail.com' AS emailAddress,
  '0123456678' AS phoneNuber,
  50.00 AS balance
```

Now, while this works in a direct SQL query, when porting the *working* query over to Android, you'll want to adapt for use with *placeholders* - that is, the SQL command will look like `insert into user_table values (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)` (where each `?` is a placeholder) and then an *array of values* will be supplied to the appropriate method call that uses the SQL string.

Android also supports the basic forms like [SQLiteDatabase.insert](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29) which are very useful and take care of lots of the "common gunk". The documentation for [execSQL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL%28java.lang.String%29) suggests *not* using execSQL for basic INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE operations, which is good advice for common scenarios - multiple calls to `insert` within a single transaction will be as "good" (and perhaps better, from a code maintenance viewpoint) as a more complex manual multi-insert.

Answer (score 0):

[Refer the docs to learn about sqlite queries](http://www.sqlite.org/lang.html).

your syntax is wrong, insert text within quotes `'TEXT GOES HERE'` and you have missed a `,`

Comment: This is *still incorrect* for several reasons (including a regression).